# Auto slash(/) for date input using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Auto slash(/) with leading and trailing space in a date value is working fine.

```js
var date = document.getElementById('date');

    function checkValue(str, max) {
      if (str.charAt(0) !== '0' || str == '00') {
        var num = parseInt(str);
        if (isNaN(num) || num <= 0 || num > max) num = 1;
        str = num > parseInt(max.toString().charAt(0)) 
               && num.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + num : num.toString();
      };
      return str;
    };

    date.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
      this.type = 'text';
      var input = this.value;
      if (/\D\/$/.test(input)) input = input.substr(0, input.length - 3);
      var values = input.split('/').map(function(v) {
        return v.replace(/\D/g, '')
      });
      if (values[0]) values[0] = checkValue(values[0], 12);
      if (values[1]) values[1] = checkValue(values[1], 31);
      var output = values.map(function(v, i) {
        return v.length == 2 && i < 2 ? v + ' / ' : v;
      });
      this.value = output.join('').substr(0, 14);
    });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="date" />
```

But when I tried to remove the space before and after slash(/).
But when I deleting each character using backspace key, slash is not deleting.

Below is what I tried.

```js
var date = document.getElementById('date');

    function checkValue(str, max) {
      if (str.charAt(0) !== '0' || str == '00') {
        var num = parseInt(str);
        if (isNaN(num) || num <= 0 || num > max) num = 1;
        str = num > parseInt(max.toString().charAt(0)) 
               && num.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + num : num.toString();
      };
      return str;
    };

    date.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
      this.type = 'text';
      var input = this.value;
      if (/\D\/$/.test(input)) input = input.substr(0, input.length - 1);
      var values = input.split('/').map(function(v) {
        return v.replace(/\D/g, '')
      });
      if (values[0]) values[0] = checkValue(values[0], 12);
      if (values[1]) values[1] = checkValue(values[1], 31);
      var output = values.map(function(v, i) {
        return v.length == 2 && i < 2 ? v + '/' : v;
      });
      this.value = output.join('').substr(0, 10);
    });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="date" />
```

Please suggest me to rectify this.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```js
var date = document.getElementById('date');

    function checkValue(str, max) {
      if (str.charAt(0) !== '0' || str == '00') {
        var num = parseInt(str);
        if (isNaN(num) || num <= 0 || num > max) num = 1;
        str = num > parseInt(max.toString().charAt(0)) 
               && num.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + num : num.toString();
      };
      return str;
    };

    date.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
      this.type = 'text';
      var input = this.value;
      if (/\D\/$/.test(input)) input = input.substr(0, input.length - 3);
      var values = input.split('/').map(function(v) {
        return v.replace(/\D/g, '')
      });
      if (values[0]) values[0] = checkValue(values[0], 12);
      if (values[1]) values[1] = checkValue(values[1], 31);
      var output = values.map(function(v, i) {
        return v.length == 2 && i < 2 ? v + ' / ' : v;
      });
      this.value = output.join('').substr(0, 14);
    });
```

```css
input {
    word-spacing:-3px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="date" />
```

You can 'cheat' and use some CSS:

```
word-spacing:-3px;
```

This moves the `/` closer to the text.

The reason it doesn't work when you remove the spaces from the JavaScript is because your code is looking for a string length of `2`, but the string length goes to `3` when you add the `/` with no spaces.

Comment: Thank for your answer. But  how to do it with `JavaScript`? Why it is not deleting the `/`?

Comment: No worries - I hope I helped! @BanuPriya - if it did, please mark this answer as 'answered' when you can :)

Comment: I explained why it didn't work with JavaScript @BanuPriya

Comment: is there any chance with Javascript?

Comment: Small specification for non-US dates, invert those lines: `checkValue(values[0], 12)` and `checkValue(values[0], 31)`

Comment: It is also possible to use \U200b Character which is a zero width space.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a alternate answer even though [Albzi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44138117/4760460) works perfectly fine. You can use the `keydown` event and check if backspace or delete is being pressed and `return false` in your event. I also added a `maxlength` of 10 to your `input` element so it does not exceed 10 characters.

```js
var date = document.getElementById('date');

function checkValue(str, max) {
  if (str.charAt(0) !== '0' || str == '00') {
    var num = parseInt(str);
    if (isNaN(num) || num <= 0 || num > max) num = 1;
    str = num > parseInt(max.toString().charAt(0)) && num.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + num : num.toString();
  };
  return str;
};

date.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  this.type = 'text';
  var input = this.value;
  var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;

  if (key == 8 || key == 46)    // here's where it checks if backspace or delete is being pressed
    return false;
    
  if (/\D\/$/.test(input)) input = input.substr(0, input.length - 1);
  var values = input.split('/').map(function(v) {
    return v.replace(/\D/g, '')
  });
  if (values[0]) values[0] = checkValue(values[0], 12);
  if (values[1]) values[1] = checkValue(values[1], 31);
  var output = values.map(function(v, i) {
    return v.length == 2 && i < 2 ? v + '/' : v;
  });
  this.value = output.join('').substr(0, 10);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="date" maxlength="10" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this come up as a requirement for an application that I am building and I implemented my solution like this.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    Date.prototype.toShortDateString = function() {
        return (this.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + this.getDate() + "/" + this.getFullYear();
    }
    //#region CUSTOM FUNCTIONS FOR DATEPICKERS
    function isTextSelected(input) {
        if (typeof input.selectionStart == "number" && input.selectionStart != input.value.length && input.selectionStart != input.selectionEnd) {
            return true;
        } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined") {
            input.focus();
            return document.selection.createRange().text == input.value;
        }
        return false;
    }
    function isNumber(e) {
        var allowedKeys = [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105];
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, allowedKeys) != -1 && !e.originalEvent.shiftKey) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    function isBackspace(keyCode) {
        var allowedKeys = [8];
        if ($.inArray(keyCode, allowedKeys) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    function isAllowedKey(keyCode) {
        var allowedKeys = [9, 13, 16, 37, 38, 39, 40];//191,111];
        if ($.inArray(keyCode, allowedKeys) != -1) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    //#endregion
    $.fn.extend({
        allowMMDDYYYY: function (validate) {
            $(this).keydown(function (e) {
                var that = this;
                if (!isNumber(e) && !isBackspace(e.keyCode) && !isAllowedKey(e.keyCode)) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                } else if ($(that).val().length == 10 && !isBackspace(e.keyCode) && !isAllowedKey(e.keyCode)) {// && !isTextSelected(e.target) && isNumber(e.keyCode)) {
                    if(!isTextSelected(e.target) && isNumber(e))
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            });
            $(this).keyup(function (e) {
                var that = this;
                var value = $(that).val();
                if (e.keyCode != 8 && !isAllowedKey(e.keyCode)) {
                    switch (value.length) {
                        case 2:
                            $(that).val(value + "/");
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            if (value.indexOf("/") == -1) {
                                $(that).val(value.substr(0, 2) + "/" + value.substr(2, 1));
                            }
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            if (value.substr(0,3).indexOf("/") == -1) {
                                $(that).val(value.substr(0, 2) + "/" + value.substr(2, 2));
                            }
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            if (e.target.selectionStart == value.length) {
                                if (e.target.selectionStart != 1) {
                                    $(that).val(value + "/");
                                }
                            }
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            if (e.target.selectionStart == value.length) {
                                if (value.substr(5).indexOf("/") == -1) {
                                    $(that).val(value.substr(0, 5) + "/" + value.substr(5, 1));
                                }
                            } else if (e.target.selectionStart == 2) {
                                $(that).val(value.substr(0, 2) + "/" + value.substr(2))
                                e.target.selectionStart = 3;
                                e.target.selectionEnd = 3;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            if (e.target.selectionStart == value.length) {
                                if (value.substr(5).indexOf("/") == -1) {
                                    $(that).val(value.substr(0, 6) + "/" + value.substr(5, 2));
                                }
                            } else if (e.target.selectionStart == 2) {
                                $(that).val(value.substr(0, 2) + "/" + value.substr(2));
                                e.target.selectionStart = 3;
                                e.target.selectionEnd = 3;
                            }
                            break;
                        case 9:
                            if (value.substr(3, 5).indexOf("/") == -1) {
                                $(that).val(value.substr(0,5) + "/" + value.substr(5))
                            } else if (value.substr(0, 3).indexOf("/") == -1) {
                                $(that).val(value.substr(0, 2) + "/" + value.substr(2))
                            }
                            break;
                            //IF THE LENGTH IS 10 (ONKEYUP) THEN CALL VALIDATION ON OTHER DATEPICKER ELEMENTS.
                        case 10:
                            if (!isTextSelected(e.target)) {
                                validate();
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
    //#endregion
    $("input[data-role='datepicker']").each(function (i, o) {
        var jqueryElement = $(o);
        jqueryElement.allowMMDDYYYY(function () {
            //THIS IS MY CALLBACK FUNCTION TO ALLOW VALIDATION ON OTHER ELEMENTS 
            console.log("validating");
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" data-role="datepicker"/>
```

My requirements we to be able to enter MMddyyyy format without slashes and it would auto populate the slashes as they typed. Solution does not allow any characters but numbers,backspace, arrow keys, ctrl, and shift key. This extension also has a callback function so that you can validate other elements after a date has been entered (since i was using jquery validator).

Answer (score 0):

This is my regex solution for React:

```
// add auto "/" for date, i.e. MM/YY
  handleExpInput(e) {

    // ignore invalid input
    if (!/^\d{0,2}\/?\d{0,2}$/.test(e.target.value)) {
      return;
    }

    let input = e.target.value;

    if (/^\d{3,}$/.test(input)) {
      input = input.match(new RegExp('.{1,2}', 'g')).join('/');
    }

    this.setState({
      expDateShow: input,
    });
  }
```

Comment: This solution allows dates like 99/99, and 00/00 which are invalid.