# How to validate and display the year in input box only if it is within the given range

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an input field where the user has to enter the DOB(MM/DD/YYYY). In this whenever the user types the date or month I've been validating the date and month value while the user enters by using javascript code which I found in the stack var date = document.getElementById('date');

```
function checkValue(str, max) {
  if (str.charAt(0) !== '0' || str == '00') {
    var num = parseInt(str);
    if (isNaN(num) || num <= 0 || num > max) num = 1;
    str = num > parseInt(max.toString().charAt(0)) 
           && num.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + num : num.toString();
  };
  return str;
};

date.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  this.type = 'text';
  var input = this.value;
  if (/\D\/$/.test(input)) input = input.substr(0, input.length - 3);
  var values = input.split('/').map(function(v) {
    return v.replace(/\D/g, '')
  });
  if (values[0]) values[0] = checkValue(values[0], 12);
  if (values[1]) values[1] = checkValue(values[1], 31);
  var output = values.map(function(v, i) {
    return v.length == 2 && i < 2 ? v + ' / ' : v;
  });
  this.value = output.join('').substr(0, 14);
});

    <input type="text" id="date" />
```

By using this the user will not be able to type the date and month exceeding 31 and 12. In the same way, I would like to check the user input within the range 1900-2100. so how can I write the Javascript code for this?

This is the link in which I've found the above solution [Auto slash(/) for date input using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44137998/auto-slash-for-date-input-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about this would be to edit the checkValue function such that there are both min and max parameters as follows:

```js
function checkValue(str, min, max) {
  ...
};
```

To accomplish this, we could do this:

1. Replace `num <= 0` within the second if statement with `num <= min`.
2. Replace `num = 1;` with `num = min;`.

This gives us:

```js
function checkValue(str, min, max) {
  if (str.charAt(0) !== '0' || str == '00') {
    var num = parseInt(str);
    if (isNaN(num) || num <= min || num > max) num = min;
    str = num > parseInt(max.toString().charAt(0)) 
           && num.toString().length == 1 ? '0' + num : num.toString();
  };
  return str;
};
```

Finally, you'd now have to change your if statements within the event listener function to account for the changes we made to checkValue.

```js
if (values[0]) values[0] = checkValue(values[0], 0, 12);
if (values[1]) values[1] = checkValue(values[1], 0, 31);
if (values[2]) values[2] = checkValue(values[2], 1900, 2100);
```

EDIT: To account for the issue where you are unable to edit the year, it seems easier to redo checkValue such that it returns a boolean (as its name suggests). That way, we can leave it up to the code within the event listener to handle each case.

```js
// A simplified version of checkValue that returns a boolean instead of a number.
function checkValue(value, min, max) {
  // If the value given is a string, turn it into a number.
  if (typeof value === "string") {
    value = parseInt(value);
  }
  if (value >= min && value <= max) {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

We can use the result of checkValue along with a number length check to allow editing of a number that's less than the max length. This should result in if statements that work to address these cases, but it's unclear to me what your exact needs are here. You will have to edit the contents of the if statements as you see fit.

```js
// Day
if (values[0].toString().length >= 2 && checkValue(values[0], 0, 31)) 
    values[0] = values[0].toString();
else {
    values[0] = "31";
}

// Month
if (values[1].toString().length >= 2 && checkValue(values[1], 1, 12)) 
    values[1] = values[1].toString();
else {
    values[1] = "12";
}

// Year
if (values[2].toString().length >= 4 && checkValue(values[2], 1900, 2100)) 
    values[2] = values[2].toString();
else {
    values[2] = "2100";
}
```

Comment: Hi Nick, i have tried with this solution but when i try to enter the value it's automatically displaying the year 1900 and i'm not able to delete it at all.

Comment: That makes sense actually, an oversight on my part. If you erase a digit from the year to try and edit it, you'll wind up with a number less than 1000 which will default to the minimum value specified in checkValue. This behavior is likely too strict for your needs, so I will edit my answer and propose a change to checkValue that outputs boolean values. It should then be up to the code within the event listener function to determine what happens to valid/non-valid days, months, and years.

Comment: As per the above solution when user types a digit 2 since it's less than 1000 it automatically shows 1900 but that shouldn't be the case since it's a single value which will be entered by the user at a time. I hope I'm clear about my question.

Comment: Just edited my answer which should hopefully address this.

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks for your answer but is this solution validates the each user input or only after user has entered the DOB?

Comment: For example have a condition like year value must be in between 1900-2100. So when user types '1' it has to be displayed in the input box and for the second input if the user types '8' it should not be displayed in the input box since the range should be between 1900-2100 and so on. This is what my actual requirement was.